# ActiveRecord / Psql - How to find records where column is like and item in an array

Tags: activerecord, psql

I know you can search a column that contains any item in an array, like:

```
  arr = ["Seattle", "New York"]
    
  Company.where("location IN (?)", arr)
```

Now how do you search a column that is 'like' any item in an array?

Similar to:

```
 Company.where("location like '%Seattle%'")
```

But for each item in the array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate your array elements into a single string.

- pro: extremely easy solution
- con: if one string ends with foo and the next starts with bar and you search for foobar, then it will be a match

Conclusion: If you choose this approach, then for safety measure it would be helpful to use some separator.

You can use the similar to criteria:

```
lower(location) similar to '%(foo|bar|baz)%'
```

or you can create a table with keywords (if there are too many) and use a like criteria around the dynamic column name.